# stuck at displaying dababase data in html ( with node.js and sequelize)

Tags: html, node.js, sequelize.js

in my server.js i have this code:

```
TABLE
.findAll({ raw: true })
.then(function(asd) {
    console.log(asd);

});
```

its shows all data from my dababase in console.
so my question is: what to do to display it on my website?

html file

```
 <form action="/gdata.html" class="form-inline" method="get">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">show data</button> </form>

                </div>
```

render code

```
router.route('gdata')
.get((req, res, next) => {
    TABLE.findAll()
        .then((users) => {
            res.render('gdata', {
                users: users
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Do  you use some framework for back-end in node.js?

Comment: Yes.im using express.js

Comment: Do you render your HTML site through express? . "res.render()" ?

Comment: added code that renders

Comment: OK, good ..now u have to tell me what template r u using ?

Comment: not using any.simple html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use some type of "template engine" like [Handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars), its very easy and fun to use, you can simply send your data alongside render function and display it on your site.

Here are some [example](https://webapplog.com/handlebars/)s with handlebars.

For your app, when you render your site and send that "user" data you will just need something like this:

1. import handlebars in your app

   ```
   var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

   app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
   app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

   app.get('/', function (req, res) {
       TABLE.findAll()
         .then((users) => {
               res.render('gdata', {
                    users: users
               });
         });
   });
   ```
2. Disply your data

   ```
   <div>
      {{#each users}}
         <p>{{@index}}. {{this}}</p>
      {{/each}}
   </div>
   ```

   This will display all of your data and their index in array.